# Library for searching through mysql or pgsql?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, search, module

I know of [whoosh](https://bitbucket.org/mchaput/whoosh/wiki/Home), but it doesn't work on `SQL` such as *MySQL* and *PostgreSQL*.

Any library to do search on any, or both, with `Python`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended that you use the standard Python bindings for MySQL and PostgreaSQL to fetch data out of the database and then index these in a format that you need.

Both these databases support FULL TEXT SEARCH (a functionality that is provided by whoosh) natively - i.e. you wont need any 3rd party libraries to do Full text search **within** MYSQL or POSTGRESQL. Hence use the SQL facilities within these databases to do your full text search within the DB environment

Also, as you may be already aware - full text search engines only index the data for efficient search and retrieval. They never crawl file systems or data stores on their own - which means that you will have to write your own file system crawler or database crawler to extract data from files / tables and then store them within a search schema defined using **whoosh**.

I would also recommend taking a look at **PyLucene** which is the python port of **Lucene** a very powerful text search engine. Of course, from what I remember it appears that setting up **PyLucene** is a bit involved and I never tried it within my projects.